# finding a number in array

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have an Array {-1,0,1,2,3,4...}
I am trying to find whether an element exist in these number or not, code is not working

```
NSInteger ind = [favArray indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];
```

in ind i am always getting 2147483647

I am filling my array like this

```
//Loading favArray from favs.plist
    NSString* favPlistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"favs" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary* favPlistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:favPlistPath];

    NSString *favString = [favPlistDict objectForKey:@"list"];
    NSArray *favList = [favString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    //int n = [[favList objectAtIndex:0] intValue];

    favArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    if([favList count]>1)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<[favList count]; i++)
        {
            NSNumber *f = [favList objectAtIndex:i];
            [favArray insertObject:f atIndex:(i-1)];
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show how you created the array?  I suspect that it is not filled with NSNumber* but rather primitives.  I believe NSNumber numberWithInt returns a pointer to a NSNumber object.

Comment: @SB: you can't put primitives in an NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the value of NSNotFound, which means that favArray contains no object that `isEqual:` to `[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]`. Check your array.

After second edit:

Your `favList` array is filled with `NSString` objects. You should convert the string objects to `NSNumber` objects before inserting them in `favArray`:

```
NSNumber *f = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[favList objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
```